# SqlAlchemy Oracle StatementError When Adding to a Many-To-Many list

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I have a many-to-many relationship setup joining together rows from the same table.

Below is a simplified schema:

```
Runs:
- status
Run_Runs:
- parentRunId
- childRunId
```

I'd like to instantiate a new child run and set its parents. Doing so against a sqlite (setup in-app) or an external postgres database works as expected. When running this against an Oracle database, I see the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (exceptions.TypeError) float() argument
>   must be a string or a number [SQL: u'IN SERT INTO example."Runs_Runs"
>   ("parentRunId", "childRunId") VALUES (:parentRunId, :childRunId)']
>   [**parameters: [{ 'parentRunId': 4.0, 'childRunId': [634.0]}]**]

Below is a snippet of the `mapper` setup. Working examples can be found at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/funseiki/e645de19119cbf2beee759776b2e457b).

```
runJoinTable = tables['Runs_Runs']
runTable = tables['Runs']
saOrm.mapper(Run, runTable, version_id_col=runTable.columns.revision,
    properties={
        "children": saOrm.relationship(Run,
            secondary=runJoinTable,
            primaryjoin = runTable.c.runId == runJoinTable.c.parentRunId,
            secondaryjoin = runTable.c.runId == runJoinTable.c.childRunId,
            backref='parents')
    })
```

This is where the error occurs with my oracle setup:

```
parentRun = session.query(Run).filter_by(runId=4).first()
childRun = Run(status='queued', parents=[parentRun])
session.add(childRun)
session.commit() # Error occurs here
```

I'm unsure why, but the Oracle connector is wrapping the childRun in list before inserting in to the Runs_Runs table.

Environment:

- macOs 10.13.6
- Python 2.7.14
- SQLAlchemy 1.2.9
- cx-Oracle 7.0.0 (libclntsh.dylib.12.1)

Comment: Did you tag [postgresql] by mistake?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - Tagged postgres and sqlite, since the above code works/was tested against those two. I'm fine with removing the tags if it just adds confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by updating to SqlAlchemy version [1.3.0b1](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/changelog_13.html#change-1.3.0b1).

Looks like it may have actually been fixed at [1.2.12](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/changelog_12.html#change-1.2.12-oracle) due to [this issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4335) that occurred with cx_Oracle 7.0.

The ids were apparently being returned as a list with that particular cx_Oracle version. Per the changelog:

> Oracle param.getvalue() now returns a list, rather than a single
>   scalar value, breaking autoincrement logic throughout the Core and ORM